# Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set

Tags: warnings

I'm traying to execute this command:

```
/home/sumo-0.25.0/sumo/bin/netconvert --node-files=hello.nod.xml
--edge-files=hello.edg.xml --output-file=hello.net.xml
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, using built in type maps.
Error: Could not open nodes-file 'hello.nod.xml'.
Quitting (on error).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a warning only. If you want to get rid of it, do something like

```
export SUMO_HOME=/home/sumo-0.25.0/sumo/
```

in your shell. The second one is the real error. It indicates that the file in question is not accessible. Is the file `hello.nod.xml` in your current working directory and readable?